# CSS Div floats to the left of the page?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, safari, css-float

I have many pages, all with the same div and the same css applied to them all... but for some reason three of these pages, the container just floats left of the page?
It looks fine in Safari/FF but in IE these pages just float the div left?

I think the other browsers might be compensating for this error, but IE not?

Any ideas :(

Comment: Post your CSS and HTML, or visit Doctype.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an open tag or some other html syntax error. Have you validated the code?
http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

Without your code, it is hard to tell.
But the behaviour seems more some CSS specification that isn't well supported in IE.

First of all, as Nino said, validate your code. Both HTML and CSS.
After taht, if you have no errors, check [QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/) to see if the CSS you are using is well supported in IE.